# Посылка сообщения в другое приложение

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Имеются 2 независимых приложения с почти идентичным кодом. В одном из них генерируем сообщение (нажав на мышку) и вместе с сообщением высылается указатель на структуру.

**Вопрос:** как можно выслать сообщение из одного приложения, а перехватить другим без появления синего экрана.

Что уже пробовал:

```
//Высылаемая структура, есть глобальный объект структуры - ball
struct ballXY
{
    bool state;
    int azaz;
};
ballXY ball = {false, 666};
// а так же message для нашей структуры
const UINT ball_msg = RegisterWindowMessage((LPCWSTR)("ball"));
```

Функция `CALLBACK` выглядит как-то так:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (message == ball_msg)
    {
        ball = *(ballXY*)lParam;
        return 0;
    }
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        //рисуем тут
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if (!ball.state)
            ball.state = true;
        break;
    case WM_TIMER:
        if (ball.state) {
            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, ball_msg, NULL, (LPARAM)&ball);
            ball.state = false;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Итог:** запустив 2 приложения, я нажал на правую кнопку мыши в одном - закрашился эксплорер, часть программ закрылась.

Comment: Вы все-таки бсод словили? Очень интересно!
По сути вопроса: адресные пространства процессов изолированы. И отправка указателя приведет к попытке чтения непойми чего. Чтение адресного пространства другого процесса - ReadProcessMemory. Но лучше используйте Shared Memory или другие способы общения, а не сообщения

Comment: Синий экран — это своего рода ядерный аналог «Программа выполнила недопустимую операцию...» То есть для его возникновения должно упасть само ядро Windows (к примеру, из-за кривого драйвера). От обычных программ BSOD возникнуть не может.

Comment: @Arhad еще как может! Было что-то недавно про внедрение кода из юзермода в ядро и передачу на него управления.

Comment: Рекомендую посылать данные между приложениями через именованный канал (pipe), а сообщения использовать лишь как уведомление о *факте* появления данных в этом канале.

Comment: @Arhad, не могли бы в ответе написать, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для межпроцессорной пересылки данных Windows API предоставляет два простых способа:

1. Именованные каналы. Хоть я и советовал этот способ в комментариях к вопросу, но он сопряжён с одной неустранимой трудностью. Кто закроет канал, если передающее приложение рухнет? Так как канал общий, то никто — будет утечка глобальных ресурсов.
2. Посылка оконного сообщения [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011(v=vs.85).aspx). Это сообщение — одно из немногих, которые обрабатываются оконной подсистемой на особых правах, а потому указанный в нём блок байт будет заботливо скопирован в адресное пространство получателя.

   При таком подходе код будет выглядеть так:

   - отправление сообщения:

     ```
     struct BallXY
     {
         bool state;
         int azaz;
     };

     // =================

     void sendBallState(BallXY& ball, HWND hParent)
     {
         // Перебираем все окна-получатели и рассылаем им обновлённые данные
         HWND hDestWnd = NULL;
         bool continueIteration = true;
         while(continueIteration)
         {
             hDestWnd = FindWindowEx(
                 /* hwndParent      */ NULL,
                 /* hwndChildAfter  */ hDestWnd,
                 /* lpszClass       */ TEXT("оконный_класс_получателя"),
                 /* lpszWindow      */ NULL);
             if(hDestinationWnd)
             {
                 COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
                 cds.dwData = 0; // Любой идентификатор; передаётся получателю как есть
                 cds.cbData = sizeof(ball);
                 cds.lpData = &ball;
                 SendMessage(hDestWnd, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)hParent, (LPARAM)&cds);
             }
             else
                 continueIteration = false;
         }
     }
     ```
   - оконная процедура:

     ```
     static void onCopyData(HWND hWnd, HWND hSourceWnd, PCOPYDATASTRUCT cds)
     {
         UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hWnd);
         // Проверяем по размеру данных, что они хотя бы примерно похожи на наши
         if(cds->cbData == sizeof(BallXY))
         {
             // Проверяем, что отправитель — подконтрольное нам окно
             TCHAR sourceClassName[256]; // Длина гарантирована MSDN
             GetClassName(hSourceWnd, sourceClassName, sizeof(sourceClassName));
             if(lstrcmp(sourceClassName, TEXT("оконный_класс_отправителя")) == 0)
             {
                 // Безопасно преобразуем типы, избегая неопределённого поведения
                 memcpy(&ball, cds->lpData, sizeof(ball));
             }
     }

     static void onTimerTick(HWND hWnd, UINT uTimerId)
     {
         UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(uTimerId);
         if(ball.state)
         {
             sendBallState(ball, hWnd);
             ball.state = false;
         }
     }

     LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
     {
         // Забываем про развесистые switch-case и пользуемся вместо этого удобными
         // message crackers из windowsx.h
         switch(message)
         {
             HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, onCopyData);
             HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_TIMER, onTimerTick);
             // ...

         default:
             return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
         }
     }
     ```

Comment: как понимаю, `lpszClass` в `hDestWnd` - это `lpszClassName` во время инициализации `WNDCLASSEX` объекта?

Comment: @koshachok, именно так.

Comment: а если я хочу кроме объекта ball высылать какое-либо сообщение, (к примеру на правую кнопку мыши закончить программу), то могу найти нужное окно(как и с объектом ball) и попросту выслать message `SendMessage(hDestWnd, end_msg, (WPARAM)hParent, NULL);` ?

Comment: @koshachok, да. Причём необязательно регистрировать именованное сообщение. Достаточно взять себе `WM_APP + любое число`, благо диапазон `WM_APP—0xBFFF` зарезервирован под нужды программ и не используется системой.

Comment: созрел вопросик, а как можно на броадкаст выслать название хендла окна? Что в стиле `Sendmessage(HWND_BROADCAST, (RegisterWindowMessage((LPCWSTR)("some"))), ?, ?)`

Comment: @koshachok, единственный способ протащить блок байт в другой процесс вместе с сообщением — `WM_COPYDATA`. Значит и название придётся пересылать тем же способом. А чтобы получатель мог различить посылку координат и оконного класса, воспользуйтесь полем  `COPYDATASTRUCT::dwData` (пусть при пересылке `BallXY` там будет `0`, а при пересылке строки — `1`).

Comment: @koshachok, и думать пока забудьте про `HWND_BROADCAST`, это накладно. Лучше ищите окна с необходимым классом и посылайте сообщение только им (как мной и сделано в коде в ответе).

Comment: Я так собственно и делаю, но при попытке сдачи проекта, мне любезно сказали : "А я хочу через броадкаст!" После часового спора сошлись на том, что окна могут через броадкаст обменяться хэндлами, или ещё чем, а потом уже использовать эти хэндлы во время отправки данных...

Comment: @koshachok, тогда ладно, шлите `WM_COPYDATA` броадкастом (но только в рамках задания). Просто нельзя дать гарантию, что если у вас на компьютере ещё чьё-то окно будет принимать `WM_COPYDATA`, оно сможет корректно переварить неожиданно пришедшие чужеродные данные. Для широковещательной рассылки удалите весь цикл `while(continueIteration)` (ибо нам теперь не надо целенаправленно  искать окна), предварительно вытащив `SendMessage` за его пределы.